# LTspice: How to add trace of two swept values

Tags: ltspice

I'm sure there is a really simple explanation for this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am sweeping the series resistance of the source voltage and I am trying to see the transfer function output.

When plotting the \$V(out)\$ and \$V(in)\$ plots separately, the different plots are shown for increasing values of series resistance. However, when I "add trace" as \$\frac{V(out)}{V(in)}\$, only one plot appears. How do I get plots of \$\frac{V(out)}{V(in)}\$ for all the different values of series resistance?

Alternatively, is there a way I can plot \$\frac{V(out)}{V(in)}\$ directly rather than going into the waveform viewer and using "add trace"?

[image: 6 plots of V(out) for sweep in series resistance, 6 plots for V(in), Only one plot for V(out)/V(in)]

Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that it's different for every step? Looks to me that there's a 6 dB difference between vout and vin for every step in the beginning, so it should just be a single line, and it also matches at the end.

Comment: This might not meet your definition of 'directly', but I've just discovered bv, behavioural voltage source, and am over-using it. On the schematic, place a bv, with an expression =V(out)/V(in), then plot the output of that.

Comment: To compute Sensitivity on the other hand is just a derivative of dG(s)/dR

Comment: @pipe Nice catch. There is a consistent difference between V(out) and V(in) which is why all the plots are overlaid and it looks like there's only one plot. I should have caught that earlier. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a voltage source as the input and if the input resistance is part of the builtin parasitic (`Rser`) then you don't need to plot `V(out)/V(in)`, `V(out)` will suffice. Otherwise, the behavioural source suggested in the comments and answer will do.

If you want to plot the result of a single value from the `.STEP` command, then use the `@<step_number>` selector, for example `V(out)@3` will plot `V(out)` with the results from the third step. This also works for `V(out)@3/V(in)@3`, and you can make combinations, `V(out)@3/V(in)@2`.

The `@` selector will not work in the behavioural source expression for obvious reasons: the behavioural expression needs to be evaluated at runtime, the latest, so you can't use `V(out)@2` before the first step has been run, for example.

Comment: Must've been in a rush because a behavioural source involving division will not work, since it's considered a nonlinear operation and its outcome cannot be linearized (dependent on the parameters of the simulation, not the circuit, itself).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a [b-source](http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29) (bv in the device list) with the function equal to V(out)/V(in)
You could then plot the voltage node of the b-source

[image]